# Socket.io ping timeout

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having a very weird issue with socket IO which till a couple of weeks it worked well. The socket appears to connect and the initial sequence of 2probe, 3probe occurs. However it seems the socket starts the process of upgrading and never finishes. The state of `socket.io.engine.upgrading` is always true till the logs indicate a `socket.io-client:socket close (ping timeout)` and it attempts to reconnect, only for the same thing to occur

Socket.io being used is version 1.7.2

**Scenario**

Node.js server running on port 443

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.server.ssl.keyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.server.ssl.certPath)
};
var ioServer = https.createServer(options, app);

var port = (config.server.ssl && config.server.ssl.enabled) ? 443 : process.env.PORT || config.server.port;
io  = require('socket.io').listen(ioServer);
```

Client side is a webapp using require

```
socket = require('socket.io-client')();
```

any ideas?

Comment: Managed to find a way around it.
with the client side ```on('connect')``` event a large payload was being emitted over socket. Reducing the size of this emit allowed the initial socket setup to continue with ease.